# Bring mailitem in front of worksheet after it is created & send without opening Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code creates an Outlook email message with attachment in the required Outlook profile. It leaves it in the outbox without opening Outlook.

The new email opens behind the worksheet, making the user click the Outlook icon on the taskbar to see it.
Also, after the user selects a contact and hits "Send", it should send without the user opening Outlook, selecting the profile and doing a "Send/Receive".

```vb
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ObjNS = OL.getNamespace("MAPI")
    ObjNS.Logon ("ABA")
Set MailSendItem = OL.CreateItem(0)

With MailSendItem
    .Subject = "Bid Proposal for: " + v_Subject
    .Body = strBody
    .Attachments.Add ("V:\\zSystem\\Bid PDF" & v_pdfFile & "")
    .Display
End With
```

The MailSendItem gets buried & un-viewable behind the Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

To open the modal window in Outlook you need to pass `true` to the `Display` method:

```
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ObjNS = OL.getNamespace("MAPI")
    ObjNS.Logon ("ABA")
Set MailSendItem = OL.CreateItem(0)

With MailSendItem
    .Subject = "Bid Proposal for: " + v_Subject
    .Body = strBody
    .Attachments.Add ("V:\\zSystem\\Bid PDF" & v_pdfFile & "")
    .Display True
End With
```

To activate an explorer or inspector window you may also use the `Activate` method if required.

But what you really need is to open a dialog programmatically to choose recipients in the following way:

```
Set olDialog = OL.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
With olDialog
 .Caption = sCap
 '.ForceResolution = True
 .AllowMultipleSelection = False
 .NumberOfRecipientSelectors = olShowTo
 .ToLabel = "Select User"
  OL.ActiveWindow.Activate
 .display
If .Recipients.Count <> 1 Then GoTo BadResult
  Debug.Print .Recipients(1).Name
  Debug.Print .Recipients(1).Address
  Debug.Print .Recipients(1).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.  The .display true did not work.  Maybe because this code ran first?  Application.DisplayFullScreen = True  These people have hundreds of contacts in Outlook.  I would be best if the can just slect a contact from the TO: button on the ready to send email.  I want to Activate or bring to front of screen the email

Comment: It is supposed to not help in your scenario. But you may try using the code I listed after for opening the address book programmatically. That should work for you.

Comment: My Client won't like this.  I just need the new email to be on top of the excel work sheet after it is created.  I thank you for your time though.  Still looking for answer.

Comment: There is no trivial way for bringing the window foreground in that case. You need to use Windows API functions to get the job done in that case.